# Anbox cloud stream failed

Tags: anbox

I'm not able to start an Anbox cloud session from the dashboard. webrtc setup is failing with error "anbox stream failed" lost webrtc connection.
The container logs shows:

```
Nov 03 15:25:49 ams-cl2fpokk0fss5fh58bm0 anbox-starter[152]: I1103 15:25:49.719795   246 streaming_server.cpp:1789] Initial signaling has completed, applying any pending ICE candidates
Nov 03 15:25:49 ams-cl2fpokk0fss5fh58bm0 anbox-starter[152]: (p2p_transport_channel.cc:1306): Failed to resolve ICE candidate hostname a45db71a-8d4f-4a13-828c-11b0117f1ea1.local with error -3
Nov 03 15:25:49 ams-cl2fpokk0fss5fh58bm0 anbox-starter[152]: (p2p_transport_channel.cc:1306): Failed to resolve ICE candidate hostname ef9dbd8f-3a4a-4edb-90dd-6ce6b450cea2.local with error -3
```

webrtc-internals data:

[image: webrtc-internals data]